# g++ template problem

Tags: c++, templates, g++, porting

I'm porting my c++ windows code (msvc & intel) to Linux (g++). The code uses lots of templates (I like metaprogramming ;-). But I can't compile this code:

```
template <class TA>
struct A
{
    template <class TAB> struct B;
};


template <class TC>
struct C {};


template <class TD>
struct D
{
    template <class TTD> class T {};
};


template<class TA>
    template<class TBA>
struct A<TA>::B : C<typename D<TA>::T<TBA> >
{
    int foo;
};
```

g++ tells me that in definition of A::B, C class has invalid template arguments. But on msvc and intel it works well! What's the problem here?
PS: Sorry, I can't post the original code, because it's too template-complicated. But this example is virtually the same and gives the same error on g++.
Thank you.

UPDATE: I've found the problem is in TBA argument of T. g++ doensn't like usage of second template in the definition.

Comment: I've seen that "template <class TA> template<class TBA> struct ..." syntax before but I've never known what it means or why it is legal syntax.  What does it mean (when "template" is mentioned twice in front of a struct like that)?

Comment: @Dennis: Its needed for the definition of nested templates outside of the enclosing template, see e.g. [here](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#outsidedef).

Comment: TA is a template argument of A, and TAB is a template argument of A::B

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the `template` keyword

```
template<class TA>
    template<class TBA>
struct A<TA>::B : C<typename D<TA>::template T<TBA> >
{
    int foo;
};
```

GCC is correct to give a diagnostic here. This is because `T` cannot be looked up in the dependent scope `D<TA>`. The meaning of the `<` after it depends on whether `T` is a template or not. The Standard says that `T` shall be assumed to be not a template and thus `T` cannot be followed by a template argument list.

`template` is like `typename` in that it tells the compiler to treat `T` as a template and that the `<` is the start of an argument list in any case. The Standard says in paragraphs `14.2/2` and `14.2/4`

> For a template-name to be explicitly qualified by the template arguments, the name must be known to refer
>   to a template.
>
> When the name of a member template specialization appears after . or -> in a postfix-expression, or after nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

In your case, you have `T` appear after the nested-name-specifier `D<TA>` which depends on the template-parameter `TA`. For the typename-specifier to parse correctly, the construct `D<TA>::T<TBA>` must interpret `T` as the name of a class template, which `14.2` forbids.

---

On that topic, it's always a good idea to try and compile with [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/index.html)

```
main1.cpp:21:37: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'T' as a dependent template name
struct A<TA>::B : C<typename D<TA>::T<TBA> >
                                    ^
                                    template 
1 error generated.
```

Comment: ok, i got it. i thout about second 'typename' keyword, but now a 'template'.

Comment: Wow, I really like this diagnostic message, now that's what you expect from the ideal compiler.